# SwiftUI @Published variable not updating

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a class with a @Published variable named userData. When the function fbLogic.getUserData() is called in this class, it updates the userData array with the data which is populated from a call to Firestore database.

The issue is that this published variable is not updating in view which access it. Or more so, these functions don't wait until the Firestore call is finished before accessing the variable. So the BarGraphView() is called with empty reports[] array, and this array isn't updated by the convertToReports() call because convertToReports() is called with an empty userData array, because fbLogic.getUserData() hasn't finished retrieving the Firebase data yet. Hopefully the code explains it better.

This is the View which is making reference to the array.

```
struct StatsView: View {
    let ID: String;
    @EnvironmentObject var statsController: StatsDataController
    @State var reports: [Report] = [Report]();
    @Binding var fbLogic: FirebaseLogic
    var body: some View {
 
       
        BarGraphView(selection: $selection, reports: $reports, originalReports: $originalReports).environmentObject(statsController).onAppear{
            fbLogic.userData = fbLogic.getUserData(uid: ID); //supposed to update the userData @Published var
            

            //These are called before fbLogic.userData has even been updated !!!
            self.reports = statsController.convertToReports(users: fbLogic.userData);
            print("fblogic data ", fbLogic.userData, " ", ID);};

    }
```

This View prints out "fb logic data []", before the call to .getUserData() has even finished, and so the call to convertToReports() happens with an empty array, instead of a populated array.

Please, how do I make this view recognise that the fbLogic.userData @Pubished array has updated and call convertToReports(), and redraw the BarGraphView with the POPULATED array.

Here is part of the fbLogic class so you can understand the call to firebase:

```
class FirebaseLogic: ObservableObject {
@Published var userData = [UserData]()
    
   
 func getUserData(uid: String) -> [UserData]{
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            userData = [UserData]()
            let auth = Auth.auth();
            let currentUser = (auth.currentUser?.uid)!
            
                let data = db.collection("UserData").document(currentUser).collection("Data")    .getDocuments { [self] (snapshot, error) in
                    guard let snapshot = snapshot, error == nil else {
                     return
                   }
                   print("Number of documents fb logic get user data: \(snapshot.documents.count ?? -1)")
                   snapshot.documents.forEach({ (documentSnapshot) in
                       
                       
                    let documentData = documentSnapshot.data()
                    //CONVERT TO userObject here (removed for simplicity)
                   
                    userData.append(userObject)

                   })
                   
                 }
                
            return userData
            
        }
```

Comment: could you try "@ObservedObject var fbLogic: FirebaseLogic" instead of "@Binding var fbLogic: FirebaseLogic"

Comment: @workingdog unfortunately this didn't change the behaviour :(

Comment: Is UserData a struct or a class?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
@ObservedObject var fbLogic: FirebaseLogic
```

in StatsView. Make sure you pass an @ObservedObject type to StatsView when you pass data to this view from parent view.

Comment: I've changed the fbLogic to @ObservedObject in both StatsView and the parent which instantiates StatsView. The behaviour is still the same though :( I instantiate the fbLogic right at the top level of the app by doing `@State var fbLogic = FirebaseLogic()` and passing down to child views. Is this the issue?

Comment: yes probably, try using @StateObject var fbLogic = FirebaseLogic()

Comment: @workingdog If it change it to StateObject then I'm actually unable to even log into the app, probably because changes in the fbLogic variable are forcing refresh at the very top level of the app and setting me back to unauthenticated. Do you know how I can make the fbLogic observed for children only? I don't want refresh at app root level, only at the level of the children e.g StatsView(). I would like the published variable to update for StatsView and the children of StatsView only, if that makes sense

Comment: to observe an object you need to instantiate it with ObservedObject or preferably StateObject.
I don't know how you could observe an object sometimes but not really at other times.
In your case maybe you could just declare "@StateObject var fbLogic = FirebaseLogic()" in StatsView, 
don't pass it in from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is that the call to `getDocuments()` is asynchronous. So when you return the array of mapped documents (consider using Codable), it is still empty.

Here is an updated version of your code that assigns the mapped documents to the published property.

```swift
class FirebaseLogic: ObservableObject {
  @Published var userData = [UserData]()
  func getUserData(uid: String) -> [UserData] {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let localUserData = [UserData]()
    let auth = Auth.auth();
    let currentUser = (auth.currentUser?.uid)! // (1)
    db.collection("UserData").document(currentUser).collection("Data").getDocuments { [self] (snapshot, error) in
      guard let snapshot = snapshot, error == nil else {
        return
      }
      print("Number of documents fb logic get user data: \(snapshot.documents.count ?? -1)")
      snapshot.documents.forEach { documentSnapshot in
        let documentData = documentSnapshot.data()
        // CONVERT TO userObject here (removed for simplicity)
        localUserData.append(userObject)
      }
      self.userData = localUserData
    }
  }
}
```

You can further improve this code by using `.map()` to transform your documents. See this [code snippet that is part](https://github.com/peterfriese/Swift-Firestore-Guide/blob/main/FirestoreCodableSamples/Screens/CustomizeMappingScreen.swift#L36) of my [article about mapping Firestore documents to/from Swift](https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/):

```swift
listenerRegistration = db.collection("programming-languages") 
  .addSnapshotListener { [weak self] (querySnapshot, error) in
    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
      self?.errorMessage = "No documents in 'programming-languages' collection"
      return
    }
          
    self?.programmingLanguages = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
      let result = Result { try queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: ProgrammingLanguage.self) }
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the answer! I'm trying to do the first option you've suggested at the moment, but the compiler complains about the line `self.userData = userData`, with the error "assigning a property to itself". Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: I updated the code to use a local variable. That being said, I would recommend using the `compactMap` approach I pointed you to. It keeps the document mapping in the closure, and assigns the mapped docs to the published property once finished. PLus, it will ignore `nil` items.